# What is the default value of arrays in java?

Tags: java, instance-variables, local-variables

if local variables need to be assigned some default value then why java provide default value for arrays declared locally.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatrixMultiplication {

int a;
int a1[][]=new int[2][2];

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a2[][]=new int[2][2];
        int b;

        MatrixMultiplication mm=new MatrixMultiplication();
        System.out.println(mm.a);
        System.out.println(mm.a1[1][0]);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(a2[1][0]);

    }
```

}

Like in above code for varible a default value is 0 and for b we have to setsome value. Then for a1[][] the dafult value of each element is 0. Till here everything is understood that have they are provided with deafult values but as a2[][] is locally declared then its elements should not be initialised by default as the java rule so how are they initialised by default with each element as 0

Comment: For integer and floating point primitives, it's 0, for booleans its `false` and for all other reference types it's `null`. (But for local variables there is no default.  You call `new` to create a new object, which initializes the local array.  So that's how the elements get set to 0, `new` does it.)

Answer (score 2):

> but as a2[][] is locally declared then its elements should not be initialosed by deaflt

There's a big difference between a *variable* and an array entry.

`b` not being initialized is a common coding error, so the compiler calls it out.

But `a2` is initialized, and the contents of an array are set to the default value for the array's element type when the array is allocated — `int[]` (or `a2[0]`) and `int` (for `a2[0][0]`), in your case.

Comment: thats what I am asking that why array is initialised to default value when it is declared locally

Comment: @Ankit: It has nothing to do with where it's declared. You're actively creating it: `new int[2][2]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("sampleArray[0] is ");
        int sampleArray[]   =   new int[7];
        System.out.println(sampleArray[0]);
     }
   }

      Output 
      sampleArray[0] is 
      0
```